# Af Query Is not refreshing after page Navigation

Tags: oracle-adf

My Jdev 11.1.7.1

I have three pages firstpage.jspx ->home.jspx->second.jspx .

I have a table related to employee history on home.jspx .I have created in appmodule a viewcriteria and dropped it as af query with table

My Navigation works  as employee logs to firstpage and then navigates to home page where he clicks search predefined af query button and sees his information .

My problem is If he goes back again to the firstpage and then to home page he sees his information populated in table .I need to clear it .

First time onload it works fine by the way if i click search then only details are populated but by navigating back and coming to same page the table is showing the details

Need a way to stop it .

Any Help Appreciated

note: Already tried the below code
I tried the below  but still table is populating while navigation

```
    RichQuery queryComp = getQryId1(); 
        QueryModel queryModel = queryComp.getModel(); 
        QueryDescriptor queryDescriptor = queryComp.getValue(); 
        queryModel.reset(queryDescriptor); 
        queryComp.refresh(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    String amDef = "model.AppModuleImpl";
    String config = "AppModuleLocal";
    ApplicationModule ami =
        Configuration.createRootApplicationModule(amDef, config);
    AppModuleImpl am = (AppModuleImpl)ami;

    ViewObjectImpl demo = am.getAlmbCmbChildallowSearchView1();
    demo.executeEmptyRowSet();
```

Thanks

Vikram

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a new instance of the AM instead of accessing the existing instance that is already there.

Also - try and just add an operation that clears the criteria in your page flow diagram before you navigate to the first page.